# JetBrains APP Android Studio Cannot invoke context menu by two fingers tapping on MacBook with M2 chip

Tags: android-studio, jetbrains-ide

Macbook Pro 13.3 M2, macOS Monterey 12.5.1.

I'm facing a problem：two fingers tapping can not invoke context menu at JetBrains app and Android Studio. But other apps work fine. Now I use two fingers click to instead of it.

Has anyone encountered this problem? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

see this issue,need to download new Idea Version
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-4765/Cannot-invoke-context-menu-by-two-fingers-tapping-on-MacBook-with-M2-chip